# Making multiple textures appear randomly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Im currently in work of making a texture pack, that changes the Ender Dragon, but i wanted to make it more interesting, and make the dragon appear different each time you fight it, without making any mods since im not really experienced with making mods. I have just 2 textures of the Dragon done, but each of them has different layouts because it was easier for me to do it. I also have a .propeties file for it, but i still don't know how to make it random so that each 1-2 times when the dragon respawns, the texture from the folder would be randomly chosen, and the chosen texture would replace the default texture of the dragon. Is it even possible to do without mods?

Comment: This *might* (i dont think so) be possible with optifine, but im pretty sure it cant be done in vanilla

Comment: I've seen some Servers have this Option, and even Texture Packs that change the texture when you change the Name of an Item. But welp, if it can't be done in Vanilla/Optifine, can it be done with Plugins/Server-side Mods?

Comment: Yes! If you give the dragon a random nametag every time they respawn.

Comment: some optifine resource packs implement random entity textures (e.g. faithful), shouldn't be too hard to replicate this but with the dragon texture

Answer (score -1):

Well you can change a mobs texture, and item textures on specific properties they have, for items this can be durability, for mobs this can be health, and other attributes. Although you could make it so the ender dragon has stages based on its health, I don't know how you would make the second ender dragon fight different but I know you can do it, as I have seen texture packs have random textures, I just don't know how you would do it, maybe you could try randomly tagging the dragon, and for each different tag the dragon skin changes?